# Magnetic anisotropy of triple bonds

Tags: nmr-spectroscopy, magnetism, carbonyl-complexes

Is the rule for shielding/deshielding areas in NMR bond dependent? The acetylene C triple bond C  has deshielding zone perpendicular to the triple bond. Will the same deshielding zone hold true for C triple bond O in metal coordinated carbonyl ligands.

Comment: In coordinated CO it's rather less then triple bond.

Comment: Let me rephrase it. In a metal carbonyl complex with a ligand that has proton located "above" CO bond, will I observe similar downfield shift for the proton as for the analogue situation with acetylene due to deshielding. Effect as illustrated for  the Anisotropy of Acetylenes  https://www.chem.wisc.edu/areas/reich/nmr/05-hmr-02-delta.htm